# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Tags: sql-server

My Windows 10 pc installed an update overnight. Today I have this message (below) when I launch SQL Server 2014 and try to 'Connect to Server'. Any ideas as to what Microsoft may have done to me please? Thanks in advance!

```
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)**
```

Comment: Verify if SQL Server service is running..

Comment: If it is, can anyone else connect from a different terminal?

Comment: Hi Rajesh. This is a stand-alone pc I use for software development. Not networked.